# How to put both image and text into a cell for jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am doing a project where we want to put both image and text into one single cell. And also, we want to be able to change the image when we click (or double click) the image. Basically, the image part represents 1 bit (ON/OFF) information. Meanwhile, we also want to be able to edit text when click (or double click) the text part. Later, we may have more image items in one cell.

Can anybody give me a suggestion? I am currently trying to put a small 1x2 table inside the cell which does not really look good. Thanks in advance.

[image: cell with both image and text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a button in the front. Which is not pretty, but it works.